# Error variable is possibly undefined in inner function but asserted in outer function

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript compiler throws an error for the following code:

```js
function assert(condition: any): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error('assert failed');
  }
}

class Cake {
    eat() {}
}

function maybeEatCake(cake?: Cake) {
    assert(typeof cake !== 'undefined');

    function nested() {
        cake.eat(); // error: 'cake' is possibly 'undefined'
    }

    cake.eat();
}
```

Why is `cake` possibly undefined in the inner function `nested()`? The assertion in the outer function checks that it is not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of *function hoisting*. When compiling the code, the inner function declaration is "moved" to the beginning of the outer function, *before the assertion*. Because the assertion now happens *after* the inner function declaration, `cake` can still be undefined.

If you use a `const` variable and an arrow function, you do not get the error, because `const` variables are not hoisted.

```js
function assert(condition: any): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error('assert failed');
  }
}

class Cake {
    eat() {}
}

function maybeEatCake(cake?: Cake) {
    assert(typeof cake !== 'undefined');

    const closure = () => {
        cake.eat(); // no error here!
    }

    cake.eat();
}
```